# Graphileon CORS issues

Tags: graphileon

I use Graphileon and try to connect by Chrome by I have CORS issue and can not connect.

Does anyone have an idea?

See Logs:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Graphileon 2.7.1 is available now, which should solve your problem. You can request a download link from here https://graphileon.com/request-graphileon-application/